# Use short name of Program Files in wix

Tags: c#, windows, wix, windows-installer, environment-variables

I am using Wix to create an msi for an application

An environment variable is set in the AppName.wxs:

```
<Component Id="MyAppEnvVar" Directory="TARGETDIR" Guid="eabcc802-6853-4db8-b827-    985db85683cf">
      <Environment Id="MyAppEnv" Action="set"
     Name='MyApp_HOME'
     Part='all'
     System="yes"
     Value="[BinDir]"/>
   </Component>
```

BinDir is specified here:

```
<Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
       <Directory Id='MyAppDir' Name='MyApp'>
         <Directory Id='ClientDir' Name='$(env.MyAppDIR)'>
            <Directory Id='BinDir' Name='$(var.PRODUCTVERSION)'>
```

This sets the environment variable 'MyApp_HOME' to C:\Program Files (x86)\MyAPP\Client\2.0.0.0

What I want to do is set MyApp_HOME to the short name as follows:
c:\Progra~2\MyAPP\Client\2.0.0.0

I have looked at SHORTFILENAMES property but not sure how this fits in with the .wxs file.

Is is possible to use the short name of program files in Wix?

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `SHORTFILENAMES` to a value in your MSI and that will force everything to be installed to short paths. That is the closest thing that **may** work but will have side-effects for any paths you are used to seeing in long form.

The `Registry/@Value` attribute allows you to use the syntax `[!FileId]` to get the short path to a `File` with matching `Id` attribute. Unfortunately, that doesn't work for the `Environment/@Value` attribute and it doesn't work for directory identifiers either.

Which means you're stuck writing a custom action to resolve it yourself. If possible, I would recommend fixing the things that read the attribute to support long paths instead. :)